# Is it possible to implement DPDK with RDMA support?

Tags: dpdk, rdma

I have learned DPDK uses UIO to bypass kernel and I wonder whether DPDK can work with RDMA.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please clarify your question? Are you asking `how to implement RDMA with DPDK` or are you asking `can RDMA and DPDK work together`?

Comment: can you please share your update on the exact requirement?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to check. The second one is my question `can RDMA and DPDK work together`?.

Comment: @haggai_e has answered your query via bifurcated driver. there is also an alternative using VFIO too.

Comment: Does the performance decrease when using DPDK with bifurcated driver or VFIO ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible either using a [bifurcated driver](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_drivers.html#bifurcated-driver), or by using multiple virtual functions with SR-IOV.